# adding 2 IEnumerable models in 1 view

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I created a view that was working successfully with 1 view

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
<ul>
    @foreach (var fName in Model)
    {
        var name = fName;
        var link = @Url.Content("~/Content/archives/mgamm/") + name.Replace(" ", "%20");

        <li style="list-style:none; font-size:1.2em;">
            <a href="@link">@name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
@if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Archives", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="File" name="file" id="file" value="Choose File" />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        }
    </div>
}
```

With a Controller

```
namespace plantationmvc.Controllers
{
    public class ArchivesController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Archives/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/archives/mgamm");

            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            var files = dir.EnumerateFiles().Select(f => f.Name);

            return View(files);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/archives/mgamm"), file.FileName);

            var data = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);

            using (var sw = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                sw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

---

However I wanted to add another snippet like this on the same page, but with a different content path.

How do I add another model to this page?

I just had a controller and View, so I created a ViewModel creating 2 classes

```
namespace plantationmvc.Models
{
    public class ArchivesViewModel
    {
        public CommModel Model1 { get; set; }
        public MeetModel Model2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CommModel>              
    }
    public class MeetModel 
    {
        public IEnumerable<MeetModel>
    }
}
```

When I try to pass this into my view as `@model IEnumerable<plantationmvc.Models.CommModel>` it says it does not exist in the namespace.

Comment: That can't compile. What is your *real* code?

Comment: @Amit added in controller view; the model snippet is what I did to attempt adding a 2nd model in and edit the `IEnumerable<string>` model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{
 public class ArchivesViewModel
 {
    public IEnumerable<CommModel> Model1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MeetModel> Model2 { get; set; }
 }

 public class CommModel
 {
    //properties of CommModel 

 }
 public class MeetModel 
 {
   //properties of Meet Model
 }

 }
```

And add the view `@model plantationmvc.Models.ArchivesViewModel`

Comment: Would I add the `public ActionResult Index()` `var`'s inside the CommModel properties as if it were another controller? and `return (View)`

Comment: you should add only data that is required on index view to the viewModel

Comment: Been busy but getting back into looking at this, what changes would I make to the controller? Do I move the necessary data on the controller to the model?

Comment: yes data belongs to model and you can combine multiple models to send them to view.Controller only place that handles request and updates models or persistence to db , or you can create service classes to get thin controllers

Answer (score 2):

You need any type for your model which has two collections in it.

It can be either your type (e.g. `ArchivesViewModel` from the answer above) or you can even use [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx).

Controler:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var list1 = new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
    var list2 = new[] { "10", "20", "30", "40", "50" };
    var model = Tuple.Create<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>>(list1, list2);
    return View(model);
}
```

View `Index.schtml`:

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>>

@foreach (var a in Model.Item1)
{
    <h2>@a</h2> 
}
@foreach (var b in Model.Item2)
{ 
    <h3>@b</h3>
}
```

Comment: While `Tuple` certainly would work, personally I find `Item1`, `Item2`, `ItemX` to be less than helpful when it comes time for the consumer of the  tuple to actually use it.

Comment: Agree. It is less readable. But sometimes it annoys that in C# you have to create types for every simple task. So `Tuple`, `Action`, `Func` are good example when you can use .NET types and don't have to create your own ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I add each set of `var`'s to to the controller. I need to get the view to return (files) but both set of files.